# How to show error message using HandleTextChanged event using xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have created two textbox fields which is username and password so my question is how to show the error message like "field cannot be empty" for password field using HandleTextChanged event If suppose it was empty?

### Here is my xaml code:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginUser"
             x:Class="LoginUser.MainPage">
  <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="50" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Entry x:Name="txtUsername"  Placeholder="Username"></Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="txtPassword" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True">
      <Entry.Behaviors>
        <local:ValidationBehavior/>
      </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
    <Button Text="Log In" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="##ff77D065" Clicked="Button_Onclick"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

### Here is my ValidationBehaviour.cs file code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UIKit;

namespace LoginUser
{
    public class ValidationBehavior: Behavior<Entry>
    {
        const string pwRegex = @"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$";
        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
        {
            bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        }

        void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            bool IsValid = false;
            IsValid = (Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, pwRegex));
            ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;

        }
        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
        {
            bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you can either user a DisplayAlert to popup an error message, or use a label that is not visible and only display it when the error condition is met

Comment: I used DisplayAlert and working fine. So thanks Jason.